# no breadboard LED output

Tags: arduino, intel, intel-edison

I'm making a simple temperature sensor to light one of two LEDs depending on the temperature.

For some reason the LED output only blinks the onboard LED (pin 13 on the Edison) once.

My temperature output is working fine, but I'm not sure why my code is working incorrectly.

Photo of the wiring here.

[image: Photo of the wiring]

```cpp
int temppin = 0;
int ledhigh = 7;
int ledlow = 8;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(temppin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledhigh, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledlow, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()                     
{

 int tempout = analogRead(temppin);  


 float volts = tempout * 5.0;
 volts /= 1024.0; 
 float temp = (volts - 0.5) * 100 ; 
 Serial.print(temp); Serial.println(" celsius");

 if (temp > 0){
  Serial.print("high temp =");
  digitalWrite(ledhigh, HIGH);
 } else {digitalWrite(ledlow, HIGH);
   Serial.print("low temp");
 } 


 delay(3000);                                   
}
```

Comment: Try switching the LEDs (so the high is the low). If you get the same result ... then I'm confused. Code and wiring looks fine.

Comment: by flipping the LED + and - or the code? I tried both. same result. 330 ohm resistors if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried switching out the switching the pins for the wiring (using other pins than 0, 1, 2)? Don't think it should matter, but you're missing an newline after the else {

Comment: added newline and tried pins 7 and 8. same result. tried manual reboot of board and reboot via ssh. same result.

Comment: Sorry i was slow but i foud the problem, you are using the analog "input pins" for output and that dosen't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you're trying to use the analog input pins as output. You need to use the digital pins.

As explained in this video:

https://youtu.be/BtLwoNJ6klE?t=50s